# node.js event emitters binding to mulitple instances

Tags: events, node.js, eventemitter

If I have a class that listens to event emitters, is it wrong practice to bind on every instance?

```
function MyClass() {

    emitter.on('ready', function() {
    // do something
    });

}

myclass = new MyClass();
```

If I call emitter.on() multiple times, it warns me.

> (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11
>   listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

Are event emitters meant to be bound only once per module, outside of class instances?

If this is wrong, then how do I access the class instance when events are triggered?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is that your attaching 11 event listeneres to the `ready` event on a single event emitter.

Generally when you listen to the same event multiple times on a single event emitter, it's likely that's a bug. For example say you have an http event emitter, if your listening on the `request` event 11 times that's probably a bug, you only want to listen and handle request once.

This is a debugging tool. You can get around this by doing

`emitter.setMaxListeners(500); // or whatever you think is a sensible limit`

Comment: Late to the party, but worth also noting that `setMaxListeners(0)` disables the warning altogether.

Comment: That's the same as `setMaxListeners(Infinity)`